# How to add single quotes to a string during the load statement in QlikView?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I know that after loading the data we can add single quotes to every string record in a table in the front-end. I want to know how to add quotes to all the strings in a field in the back-end i.e while loading the document.

**Example**: I have a table called `[test table]`.
This table has a field called `PROPERTIES`.
The `PROPERTIES` field consists of 10 records, like `good`, `bad`, `average` etc all in the string format.

I want it to be displayed as `'good'`, `'bad'`, `'average'` etc. in the dashboard. I want those single quotes. I know how to do this after loading the data, I need to know how to do this while loading the data.

I tried this:

```
[test table]:
Load 
    ' & PROPERTIES & ' as Propertiesquot,
    [Product Name]
From .....
```

Answer (score 3):

As you may have found, adding single quotes around a field name causes QlikView to treat it as a string literal.

In your example:

```
[test table]:
Load 
    ' & PROPERTIES & ' as Propertiesquot,
    [Product Name]
From .....
```

This would cause the field `Propertiesquot` to contain `' & PROPERTIES & '` for all records.

Instead you can use the `chr()` function to return a single quote as follows (ASCII code 39 is an apostrophe):

```
[test table]:
Load 
    chr(39) & PROPERTIES & chr(39) as Propertiesquot,
    [Product Name]
From .....
```

This will then add single quotes around each value of your `PROPERTIES` field during a reload.

As a side note to those interested, I am not aware of a method to escape single quotes in QlikView.

For more detail on this subject, see the topic "Quotation Marks in Scripting" in the installed help, and also https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2013/04/09/quoteology.